# SmoothDamp with position clamp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a camera following a player using 'SmoothDamp' however I wish to stop the camera going out of bounds of the background sprite.

I can do this separately with the 'SmoothDamp' but not with 'Mathf.Clamp'.

```
transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPos, ref velocity, smoothTime);
```

or

```
bgBounds = GameObject.Find("Background").GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
bottomLeftLimit = bgBounds.sprite.bounds.min;
topRightLimit = bgBounds.sprite.bounds.max;

transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, bottomLeftLimit.x, topRightLimit.x), Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, bottomLeftLimit.y, topRightLimit.y), transform.position.z);
```

Comment: Does it successfully keep the center point of the camera's view within the background's bounds? Also, are you using an orthographic camera?

Comment: The first snippet of code is what I am using and the camera is going out of bounds. I am not using the second snippet but it is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you using an orthographic camera?

Comment: Sorry yes, and it is a 2d top down game

Comment: This looks like it's being called in `Update`. You should move the `bgBounds = GameObject.Find` call to `Start` if you haven't already. `GameObject.Find` is an expensive operation.

Comment: Yes, I have `bgBounds = GameObject.Find` in the `Start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to ensure that the boundaries of an orthographic camera don't leave a `Bounds` you need to include the extents of the camera's view as padding to your clamps.

You can use `camera.orthographicSize` and `camera.aspect` to get the extents of the camera's view.

```
// Clamp the target position to be within the boundaries

float cameraVertExtent = camera.orthographicSize;
float cameraHorizExtent = camera.orthographicSize * camera.aspect;

Vector3 clampedTargetPos = new Vector3(
        Mathf.Clamp(targetPos.x, bottomLeftLimit.x+cameraHorizExtent, topRightLimit.x-cameraHorizExtent), 
        Mathf.Clamp(targetPos.y, bottomLeftLimit.y+cameraVertExtent, topRightLimit.y-cameraVertExtent),
        transform.position.z
        );

// SmoothDamp to the clamped target position.
transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, clampedTargetPos, ref velocity, smoothTime);
```

If you weren't using an orthographic camera, you would need to find where the edges of the camera's view intersect with the background, and solve for the necessary padding from there.

Comment: thank you, this makes sense. However when I go to the top of the screen for example the camera moves to the bottom of the screen rather then just stopping. When I move player down again the camera moves up to meet the player

Comment: I did have to change the `camera.orthographicSize` to `getComponent<Camera>(). orthographicSize`

Comment: If you're calling this code on every frame, you should add a `private Camera camera` property to the class and put `camera = getComponent<Camera>();` in `Start` so that you don't have to call `GetComponent` on every frame. it is an expensive operation